# Identifying where joins can be made between two sql server tables

Tags: sql-server

Very new to sql server. I have a db with about 20 tables each with around 40 columns. How can I select two tables and see if they have any columns in common?

I basically want to see where I can make joins.. If there's a better way of quickly telling where I can combine info from two tables that could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in relational databases there is not such a concept of "joinable tables and/or columns". You can always list two relations (= tables) crossing every row in one relation with each row of the other (the cross/carthesian product of them) and then filter those based on some predicate (also called a "join", if the predicate involves columns of both relations).

The idea of "joinable" tables/columns comes into being only when thinking about the database schema. The schema's author can ask the database engine to enforce some referential integrity, by means of foreign keys.

Now if your database schema is well done (that is, its author was kind/clever enough to put referential integrity all over the schema) you can have a clue of which tables are joinable (by which columns).

To find those foreign keys, for each table you can run `sp_help 'databasename.tablename'` (you can omit the `databasename.` part, if it is the current database).

This command will output some facts about the given table, like its columns (along with their datatypes, requiredness, ...), its indexes and so on. Somewhere near the end it will list foreign keys along with where (if ever) its primary key is imported as foreign key on other tables.

For each key imported as foreign key on other table you have a candidate predicate for a join.

Please note that this procedure will only work if the foreign keys are set correctly. If they aren't, you can fix your database schema (but to do this you must know already which tables are joinable anyway). Also it won't show you joinable tables on other databases (in the same or linked server).

This also won't work for views.

Comment: I tried sp_help 'tablename' and got the following error message: "The object 'tablename' does not exist in database 'master' or is invalid for this operation."

Comment: I got your suggested solution (i.e. sp_help) to work. But I can't see any reference to primary/foreign keys or potential joins with other tables - is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see in the SQL Management Studio, in the database diagram, there you find the relations between tables.